# Nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure antMatchers after anyRequest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying this code but get this exception:nested exception is:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure antMatchers after anyRequest.

**Java code**

```
package com.cris.cms.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encodePWD());
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.csrf().disable();  http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll().and()
.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/secure/**").authenticated().anyRequest().hasAnyRole("ADMIN").and()
                .formLogin().permitAll();
    }
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encodePWD() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

- You don't need to call `.authorizeRequests()` multiple times but even if you call it, it is not an error. If you remove the `.authorizeRequests()` multiple calls, and format it, it would be look as follows:

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/secure/**").authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .permitAll();
    }
```

- So now think of it as of multiple if else if else like below

```
   if (condition1) {
      doX();
   } else if (condition2) {
      doY();
   } else {
      doZ()
   }
```

- As it self explains, `anyRequest()` will evaluate to true always. So if you put `anyRequest()` as the first condition, it will never go past the first `if` block. So you always have to put `anyRequest()` as the last line within `authorizeRequests()`
- So put specific urls matching first. If you have `antMatchers("/rest/**")` and `antMatchers("**")`, you have to put `antMatchers("/rest/**")`
- Similarly you cannot have more than one `else` blocks because it is the last one without condition. You have to remove one of `.anyRequest().permitAll()` or `.anyRequest().hasAnyRole("ADMIN")`
- So it will become

```
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers("/secure/**").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers("/admin specific url").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .permitAll();
    }
```